# Julia parallel computing over multiple nodes in cluster

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing, julia

I am running some jobs on a shared cluster and I've been trying to use more than 1 node at a time. While using `julia -p #processors` works for the cores on one node, it doesn't find the other nodes. 
The cluster is using SGE and I tried a lot of different ways to make the nodes work, but only one was working. Is there an easy way built in Julia to launch Julia with `julia -mpi 32` or something similar?
Using

```
using ClusterManagers
println(nworkers(),nprocs(),Sys.CPU_CORES)
ClusterManagers.addprocs_sge(16)
ClusterManagers.addprocs_sge(15)
println(nworkers(),nprocs(),Sys.CPU_CORES)
```

doesn't work (I have submitted a job reserving 2 nodes with 16 cores each on the SGE), the output file of the job is empty and instead I get 16  different output files `julia-70755.o8252776.*` `(* = 1...16)` with the following text:

```
julia_worker:9009#192.168.17.206
Master process (id 1) could not connect within 60.0 seconds.
exiting.
```

Starting Julia with `julia --machinefile $PE_HOSTFILE` also failed with:

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.168.18.10' to th
e list of known hosts.
ERROR: connect: invalid argument (EINVAL)
 in uv_error at ./libuv.jl:68 [inlined]
 in connect!(::TCPSocket, ::IPv4, ::UInt16) at ./socket.jl:652
 in connect!(::TCPSocket, ::SubString{String}, ::UInt16) at ./socket.jl:688
 in connect at ./stream.jl:959 [inlined]
 in connect_to_worker(::SubString{String}, ::Int16) at ./managers.jl:483
 in connect(::Base.SSHManager, ::Int64, ::WorkerConfig) at ./managers.jl:425
 in create_worker(::Base.SSHManager, ::WorkerConfig) at ./multi.jl:1786
 in setup_launched_worker(::Base.SSHManager, ::WorkerConfig, ::Array{Int64,1}) a
t ./multi.jl:1733
 in (::Base.##669#673{Base.SSHManager,Array{Int64,1}})() at ./task.jl:360
 in sync_end() at ./task.jl:311
 in macro expansion at ./task.jl:327 [inlined]
 in #addprocs_locked#665(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Base.SSHManager) at ./mul
ti.jl:1688
 in (::Base.#kw##addprocs_locked)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#addprocs_locked, ::Bas
e.SSHManager) at ./<missing>:0
 in #addprocs#664(::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Base.SSHManager) at ./multi.jl:1
658
 in (::Base.#kw##addprocs)(::Array{Any,1}, ::Base.#addprocs, ::Base.SSHManager) 
at ./<missing>:0
 in #addprocs#764(::Bool, ::Cmd, ::Int64, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::Array{An
y,1}) at ./managers.jl:112
 in process_options(::Base.JLOptions) at ./client.jl:227
 in _start() at ./client.jl:321
UndefRefError()
```

I was suggested to use the **MPI.jl** package, but it doesn't look to me like it really supports the julia parallel syntax, at the way I'm using it by just writing @sync @parallel before a for loop that I want to run in parallel (i.e. Metropolis-Montecarlo).

Comment: First hit in Google gives me (hopefully) the answer to your question:
http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/multi-node-parallelism-in-julia-on-an-hpc/

Comment: Yes, the machinefile method from my blog post will work for this. I show exactly how to do it on an SGE cluster. You may have to find out how your cluster names its machine file though... but if you start an MPI job, it'll show up.

Comment: @ChrisRackauckas Nope `julia --machinefile jbtest-pe_hostfile_mpich.$JOB_ID test.jl` didn't work as it returned `ERROR: SystemError: opening file /usr4/spclpgm/opfeffer/annealing/jbtest-pe_host
file_mpich.8279159: No such file or directory`

Comment: By the way: I can't use `#$ -pe mpich 128` since: `Unable to run job: job rejected: the requested parallel environment "mpich" does not exist.` 
I use `mpi_16_tasks_per_node #NCORES`

Comment: The error you got is because you have the wrong path. Different clusters put the machine file in different places. You need to find out where it is an where it's named. Start an MPI job and ssh into the node, and look around for the file. It's likely at the cwd for the job, just named differently. The commands I gave are generally the right direction, but need to be updated to the specifics of your cluster. The mpich thing is another example of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IT team got back to me and told me that the SGE does not allow passwordless ssh, that's why `addprocs_sge()` wouldn't work. However they now added a file for the job that I can pass to Julia and told me to run the job with this script:

```
qlogin -pe mpi_28_tasks_per_node 56
module load julia/0.5.1
julia --machinefile $TMPDIR/machines
```

The machines file looks like this:

```
::::::::::::::
/scratch/8548498.1.u/machines
::::::::::::::
{hostname1}
{hostname1}
...
{hostname2}
{hostname2}
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to read the julia docs on parallel computing where there is a section on cluster managers.  Also, take a look at ClusterManagers.jl where SGE is supported:

```
julia> using ClusterManagers
julia> ClusterMangers.addprocs_sge(5)
```